# fatal llvm error upon use of LLVMBuildNeg

Tags: c, clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I want to calculate the derivative of the atan2 function, with LLVM C API calls, building the function.
This is the code:

```c
LLVMValueRef x, y, newSeedY;

x = l_as_float8(b, LLVMBuildLoad(b, l_ptr_const((void *)&pointer_1, l_ptr(TypeDatum)), ""));
y = l_as_float8(b, LLVMBuildLoad(b, l_ptr_const((void *)&pointer_2, l_ptr(TypeDatum)), ""));

newSeedY = LLVMBuildBinOp(b,
                          LLVMFMul,
                          LLVMBuildNeg(b, l_as_float8(b, seed), ""),
                          LLVMBuildBinOp(b,
                                         LLVMFDiv,
                                         x,
                                         LLVMBuildBinOp(b,
                                                        LLVMFAdd,
                                                        LLVMBuildBinOp(b,
                                                                       LLVMFMul,
                                                                       x,
                                                                       x,
                                                                       ""),
                                                        LLVMBuildBinOp(b,
                                                                       LLVMFMul,
                                                                       y,
                                                                       y,
                                                                       ""),
                                                        ""),
                                          ""),
                          "");
```

This causes the following error:

```
FATAL:  fatal llvm error: Cannot select: 0x55a789a141d0: f64 = sub 0x55a789a14988, 0x55a789a13ef8
      0x55a789a14988: f64,ch = load<(load 8 from constant-pool)> 0x55a78a4100e8, 0x55a789a16ad8, undef:i64
        0x55a789a16ad8: i64 = X86ISD::Wrapper TargetConstantPool:i64<double -0.000000e+00> 0
          0x55a789a142a0: i64 = TargetConstantPool<double -0.000000e+00> 0
        0x55a789a14920: i64 = undef
      0x55a789a13ef8: f64,ch = load<(load 8 from constant-pool)> 0x55a78a4100e8, 0x55a789a14100, undef:i64
        0x55a789a14100: i64 = X86ISD::Wrapper TargetConstantPool:i64<double 1.000000e+00> 0
          0x55a789a14780: i64 = TargetConstantPool<double 1.000000e+00> 0
        0x55a789a14920: i64 = undef
    In function: diffexpr_8_1
```

Howevver, if I change the line of the `LLVMBuildNeg()` into(meaning I remove the negation):

```
...
seed,
...
```

The error does not come up.

My question:
**Why does a simple negation cause a fatal error for llvm?**

PS: (`seed` is always handled as a float8/double, and the error is still present, if called without the cast)

Comment: If anything is unclear or need editing, please tell me, i will do my best to provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a fix, just a workaround!**

You can apparently steer clear of this issue, if you just do this instead:

```
LLVMBuildBinOp(b, LLVMFMul, x, const_containing_minus_one, "res_name");
```